# FBJS callSWF IE issue

Tags: flash, actionscript, fbjs

I have problem with Facebook JS callSWF method in IE. In all other browsers it works just fine, only IE (all versions) is trouble maker.

When I'm trying to access JS from AS, it works, but in other direction, when i try to call method declared in AS from JS (document.getElementById("swf").callSWF('myMethod');) it is not working (only IE).

I do not know if there is something with FB and their API changes...

Does anyone had or has a similar or same problem?

Thanks
K.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a bugreport on facebook:
http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=17440

Comment: There's no reason to post two answers, especially since you could've edited your original one. Stackoverflow is not a forum. Read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)